# Sorting an array by its members' dictionary's keys

Tags: objective-c

If that was a little confusing here's a visual representation:

Array > Object > Dictionary > Values

Here's some context if this helps:

An array contain playlists.  Each playlist has a dictionary.  Each dictionary contains metadata.

I need to sort the original dictionary by this metadata.

I've been pretty stumped at implementing this.  Thoughts?

**[Edit]** Changed the higher dictionary into an array

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted. You can't "sort a dictionary".

Comment: I think you want to sort an array. cause that will make much sense than sorting a dictionary. coz you get the objects/values from a dictionary using `objectForKey:` method and in an array you use `objectAtIndex:`

Comment: I've updated the original post to change the original dictionary to use arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use at least one `NSSortDescriptor`. This is basically an abstract way of representing a way to sort something. It can contain a key path (more on that in a second) or a function pointer, or some other way to compare two objects.

You'll probably want to use it with a key path. So if you have an array of `Foo` objects,  and they have a "dictionary" property that returns an `NSDictionary`,  and you want to sort the array based on a value in the dictionary under the key `@"bar"`, then the sort descriptor you'd create would be:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dictionary.bar" ascending:YES]
```

From here you can use `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors]` and pass it an array containing this `NSSortDescriptor`.